# fault-tolerant python based parser for WikiLeaks cables

Tags: python, parsing, text-parsing, bnf

Some time ago I started writing a [BNF-based grammar](http://hg.lug-jena.de/KabelJau/file/tip/cable.bnf) for the [cables which WikiLeaks released](http://wikileaks.ch/cablegate.html). However I now realized that my approach is maybe not the best and I'm looking for some improvement.

A cabe consists of three parts. The head has some [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html)-style format. This parses usually correct. The text part has a more informal specification. For instance, there is a [REF](http://hg.lug-jena.de/KabelJau/file/tip/cable.bnf#l379)-line. This should start with `REF:`, but I found different versions. The following regex catches most cases: `^\s*[Rr][Ee][Ff][Ss: ]`. So there are spaces in front, different cases and so on. The text part is mostly plain text with some special formatted headings.

We want to recognize each field (date, REF etc.) and put into a database. We chose Pythons SimpleParse. At the moment the parses stops at each field which it doesn't recognize. We are now looking for a more fault-tolerant solution. All fields have some kind of order. When the parser don't recognize a field, it should add some 'not recognized'-blob to the current field and go on. (Or maybe you have some better approach here).

What kind of parser or other kind of solution would you suggest? Is something better around?

Comment: Are you sure that you need a parser? What you described about the cables' structure sounds like a type-3-language (in chomsky's classification) which would imply that a lexer (like flex) or regular expressions are the means to "parse" the cables.

Comment: Why not just add `/ not_recognized` to each header token?

Comment: I'm not sure if I really need a parser. From my impression the parser input is more readable than a regular expression. Thatswhy I tended to favour it. I'll have a look at flex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cablemap seems to do what you're searching for: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cablemap.core/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the cables but lets take a similar problem and consider the options: Lets say you wanted to write a parser for RFCs, there's an RFC for formatting of RFCs, but not all RFCs follow it.

If you wrote a strict parser, you'll run into the situation you've run into - the outliers will halt your progress - in this case you've got two options:

1. Split them into two groups, the ones that are strictly formatted and the ones that aren't. Write your strict parser so that it gets the low hanging fruit and figure out based on the number outliers what the best options are (hand processing, outlier parser, etc)
2. If the two groups are equally sized, or there are more outliers than standard formats - write a flexible parser. In this case regular expressions are going to be more beneficial to you as you can process an entire file looking for a series of flexible regexs, if one of the regexes fails you can easily generate the outlier list. But, since you can make the search against a series of regexes you could build a matrix of pass/fails for each regex.

For 'fuzzy' data where some follow the format and some do not, I much prefer using the regex approach. That's just me though. (Yes, it is slower, but having to engineer the relationship between each match segment so that you have a single query (or parser) that fits every corner case is a nightmare when dealing with human generated input.